# AttributeError when accessing member of Java class in Jython

Tags: java, jython, attributeerror

I am trying to import my own java class into some jython code. I compiled my .java to a .class file and put the .class file into a .jar. I then include this .jar file using -Dpython.path="path/to/jar/my.jar". So far so good, no complaints when starting up my program.

However, when I get to the part of the code that uses my java class, it seems like it can't find any of the functions in my java class. I get the following  `AttributeError`:

```
AttributeError: 'pos.Test' object has no attribute 'getName'
```

Any suggestions would be much appreciated! (Code samples below.)

Java code:

```
package pos;

class Test{

    private String name;

    public Test(){
        name = "TEST";
        System.out.println( "Name = " + name );
    }

    public String getName(){
        return name;
    }   
}
```

Jython code snippet:

```
import pos.Test

...

test = pos.Test()

print 'Name = ', test.getName()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is about visibility. Your class is [package-private](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html). It will work if

```
python.security.respectJavaAccessibility = false
```

is added to the Jython registry. See https://www.jython.org/registry.html.

Or make the class public.

Answer (score 0):

You must import the Java class in the Jython code before you can use it. Something like:

```
from pos import Test

test = Test()
print 'Name = ', test.getName()
```

See [Chapter 8 of the Jython Book](http://www.jython.org/jythonbook/en/1.0/ModulesPackages.html#module-search-path-compilation-and-loading) to understand how import paths etc. work in Jython.

Comment: Sorry, I should have included more code. I have actually imported my class in the jython file I just didn't include it in the code snippet. So this isn't the problem.